# SQL adding additional columns to a query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to create a query that allows me to see all of the customers orders and to add an additional column using sql to view the total amount that the customer owes.

the following code retrieves the correct data:

```
SELECT
    cu.FName + '  ' + cu.SName as 'Name', 
    cu.Address1 + ', ' + cu.Address2 + ', ' + cu.Address3 as 'Dispatch Address', 
    cu.PostCode, 
    co.DateOrdered, co.DateDispatched, 
    ma.MaterialName, 
    it.Quantity, 
    ma.Price as 'Total' 
FROM
    Customers cu 
LEFT JOIN 
    CustomerOrder co ON co.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID 
LEFT JOIN
    ItemOrder it ON it.OrderID = co.OrderID 
LEFT JOIN 
    Materials ma ON ma.MaterialID = it.MaterialID
```

I now need to add additional code to the above to add a column to show the total amount the customer owes, but I'm stuck, can anybody help?

```
Date Order   |    Dispatch Date | Item  | QTY  |   Price | TOTAL AMOUNT FOR BOTH ROWS
2012-10-30   |    2012-11-25    | Bath  | 1    |   49.99 |  
2012-10-30   |    2012-11-25    | Sink  | 1    |   55.99 |
```

Comment: try adding amount. after total as (it.Quantity * ma.Price ) as "Amount" if both of these fields are not in same datatype then use casting

Comment: Can you create a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) with a working data model?  It will be easier to work with data from each table.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select 
  cu.FName + '  ' + cu.SName as 'Name', 
  cu.Address1 + ', ' + cu.Address2 + ', ' + cu.Address3 as 'Dispatch Address', 
  cu.PostCode, 
  co.DateOrdered, co.DateDispatched, 
  ma.MaterialName, 
  it.Quantity, 
  ma.Price as 'Total' ,
  (it.Quantity * ma.Price) 'Owe amount'
from Customers cu 
left join CustomerOrder co on co.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID 
left join ItemOrder it on it.OrderID = co.OrderID 
left join Materials ma on ma.MaterialID = it.MaterialID
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your posts,  Is there anyway that i could add rows 1 and 2 together?  This is the task that i have been given... "Create a query which shows which items have been ordered by which customers  and the total value of the orders placed by each customer"

Comment: @Annoscia - What do you mean?  Can you please edit your question with some sample data please.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    cu.FName + '  ' + cu.SName as 'Name', 
    cu.Address1 + ', ' + cu.Address2 + ', ' + cu.Address3 as 'Dispatch Address', 
    cu.PostCode, 
    co.DateOrdered, co.DateDispatched, 
    ma.MaterialName, 
    it.Quantity, 
    ma.Price as 'Total',
    sum(it.Quantity * ma.Price) over (partition by cu.CustomerID) as TotalOwed
from Customers cu 
left join CustomerOrder co on co.CustomerID = cu.CustomerID 
left join ItemOrder it on it.OrderID = co.OrderID 
left join Materials ma on ma.MaterialID = it.MaterialID
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your post, Is there anyway that i could add rows 1 and 2 together? This is the task that i have been given... "Create a query which shows which items have been ordered by which customers and the total value of the orders placed by each customer

Comment: @Annoscia How do the results of this query differ from the desired results?